# Wrong Conversion ? String => Int

Tags: php

I'm having trouble converting string to int.
The array $input holds following values:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "30" [1]=> string(2) "01" [2]=> string(9) "2013" }
```

First I remove the leading zeros, because of the octa trap. So this is my code:

```
foreach ($input as $key => $var) {
        $input[$key] = trim($var,"0");
        $input[$key] = (int)$var;
    }
```

But unfortunately the result is not statisfying.

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2013) }
```

30 is now zero? How is this possible?

Comment: Your vardump shows that the string is 6 characters long, being that a string with 30 should only be 2, it appears that you have some extra characters in the string. You could try to convert it to hex and see what the characters are.

Comment: You could preg_replace any character that isn't a digit with ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[0]=> string(6) "30"
```

This string has some non-printable characters in the beginning. It looks like 2 characters long, but in reality there are 6 of them. Such characters would cause the string to be converted to `0` as is documented.

You should try `bin2hex` on the string to see what byte values we are talking about, then use this knowledge to determine where they come from.

The `"2013"` string *also* has extra characters, although by the looks of it they are *trailing* in that case.